# Mongodb and Cakephp $all not searching for more than 1 record

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I wanted to find all documents with the id of "1" and "2".

I have this code:

```
$user = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('_id' => array('$all' => array('1', '2')))));
```

When I try to debug $user, it doesn't show anything, But when I try to search for only 1 record like this:

```
$user = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('_id' => array('$all' => array('1')))));
```

it works.

I don't know why its not searching for 2 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the end, I was able to figure out that I should use "$in" rather than "$all"

Comment: cannot, have to wait for 2 days

Comment: You don't have to wait 2 days to give an answer worth voting for =)